# Consultar Dos Tablas Usando LinQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, linq, linq-to-sql

Buenas tardes estoy teniendo un inconveniente en el codigo necesito llamar dos tablas y no me estaria saliendo

```
 IQueryable<ActasDeAsambleas> actas = db.ActasDeAsambleas;
 IQueryable<TiposActasDeAsambleas> tiposActas = db.TiposActasDeAsambleas;

 if (cboTipoAsamblea.Text != "")
                {
                    int type = Convert.ToInt32(cboTipoAsamblea.SelectedValue);
                    actas = actas.Where(a => a.IdTipoAsamblea == type);
                }
```

necesito hacer un cruce de tablas donde compare

ActasDeAsambleas.IdTiposActasDeAsambleas = TiposActasDeAsambleas.Id

y que me traiga los otros campos que tienen ambas tablas

Comment: Edita la pregunta, incluye las clases de `ActaDeAsambleas` y `TipoActasDeAsambleas`, del mismo modo, incluye información para reproducir tu escenario y datos de prueba. Aquí unas recomendaciones de cómo mejorar la calidad de preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podés hacer lo siguiente utilizando EF:

```
 var query = _context.Actas.Include(x => x.tiposActas).FirstOrDefault( x => x.IdTipoAsamblea == type);
```

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya especificado el problema que está teniendo, o en donde no haya demostrado lo que haya intentado para resolver su planteamiento. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_, y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.